# Reinstalling Visual Studio 2013 on the same machine after a clean installation of Windows

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio-2013, 32bit-64bit, windows-7-x64

I have VS2013 and am about to install it on a 32bit win7 computer.  Will I be able to use the same VS2013 licence key when I install the 64bit win7 on the same computer?  Or will it complain that the licence key has already been used on another computer, when it's actually the same computer but just with a different version of windows7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.
If you read in the [MSDN White Paper](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13350), page 13, 1st paragraph:

"All MSDN subscriptions and Visual Studio Professional are licensed on a per-user basis."

This means that until you are the only user you can re-use the same licence key even in differents machine.

Answer (score 1):

You can re-use the same license key. Since you will only be the product on one machine.